# Building Boost library RegEx in both Win32 and WinCE Platforms

Tags: c++, regex, boost, windows-ce

I want to use Boost RegEx module in Win32 as well as on the WinCE platform. We are using a common code for Win32 and WinCE platform in C++ (VS2008). Now I want to use Boost Regex in this common code. So steps which I followed are:

1. Downloaded Boost 1.55.0
2. Ran Bootstrap.bat
3. Ran bjam command to build Regex.

   `bjam --with-regex --with-date_time --with-thread toolset=msvc-9.0 variant=release threading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared`

   `bjam --with-regex --with-date_time --with-thread toolset=msvc-WM5 variant=release threading=multi link=shared runtime-link=shared`

I am using these lib files, and on Win32 platforms its building and working fine. But in CEPlatform I am getting the following error:

`libboost_regex-vc90-mt-sgd-1_55.lib(boost_regex-vc-mt-gd-1_55.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'THUMB'`

For this error I modified the user_config.bjam (in tools\build\v2 location) 
using msvc : WM5: /MACHINE:THUMB;

and then I built the same, but still I am facing this issue. Please any one help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The /MACHINE option is a linker option, when building a library that should not be relevant. It seems that the build system is using the x86 compiler. I don't know bjam in detail but you may check something about cross-compiling in its documentation or a way to configure the compiler that should be used to build your code.